# Toast resource not found Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/transient_notification.xml

Tags: android, resources, toast

### this problem is not always there, I can't find the cause of the problem, ask for help, thank you.

My code is

```
private static Toast systemToast;       

public static Toast getSystemToast(Object resId) {
    if (null == systemToast) {
         // Apps is the Application.java
        systemToast = Toast.makeText(Apps.getAppContext(), R.string.me_empty,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    String res = String.valueOf(resId);
    if (resId.getClass() == Integer.class) {
        systemToast.setText(Integer.valueOf(res));
    } else if (resId.getClass() == String.class) {
        systemToast.setText(res);
    }
    systemToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return systemToast;
}
```

/** Apps.java **/

```
  public class Apps extends Application {

    private static Apps sContext;
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    sContext = this;
}
public static Apps getAppContext() {
    return sContext;
}
```

---

In some Android equipment,  Error occurred, The error Log is:

```
  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout
/transient_notification.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x10900ef at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2720) at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2675) at 
android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1096) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:422) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368) at     
android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:282)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might be occurred, when pass context object not proper initialize or might be its referencing to null.

1.if you are using Fragment than, you can find Context in onAttach Method. And pass your **getSystemToast**  Method.

```
 **@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }**
```

2. If you are using Activity, than get Context using **getBaseContext()** Method or **ActivityName.this** both will return you context

You no need to defined function for get Context. Android provide Following Method for get Context.
1.**getApplicationContext()** Application context is associated with the Applicaition and will always be the same throughout the life cycle.

2.getBaseContext()

3.onAttach() in Fragment.